# Custom Bootstrap SCSS with React Components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sass

I am building a react-app, created with create-react-app, using bootstrap and react-bootstrap
I have a custom theme that is an npm package, and really just defines some variables.

*@myorg/theme/lib/scss/_variables.scss:*

```
$theme-colors: (
 primary: #FFFF,
 // etc...
)
```

Then I import this in my "site" theme before importing bootstrap:

*./src/index.scss:*

```
@import "~@myorg/theme/lib/scss/_variables.scss";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Now I'd like to have components with their own specific styles, that build on bootstrap:

*./src/components/MainLayout.scss:*

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_variables";
#sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid $gray-400
}
```

However when I do this, it gets rid of my theme colors, so I have to do this -
*./src/components/MainLayout.scss:*

```
@import "../../index.scss";
#sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid $gray-400
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? It seems to write the entire contents to the document (bootstrap and all) every time I do this, and I would be doing it a lot for many components. For instance, I have another component where I'd like to customize CardColumns (I actually can't get this to work no matter the import):

```
 //@import ???? I need, functions, mixins, and variables from bootstrap
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 10;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 10;
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to use bootstrap 4's scss files in modular react components? Without bloating the download size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create 1 lib.scss file to contain all my import from library
like this name lib.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

then when I create new module like admin module i will simply import like this

```
@import "./lib";
...
```

Comment: Won't this write bootstrap's and font-awesome's entire stylesheet to the document for each visible component that imports ./lib?

Comment: Correct but are you using webpack ?

Comment: Yes, via create-react-app

Comment: Then I think you can create 1 file lib.js then import lib.scss into that then it will extract into lib.css so you can have library css file to use everywhere